# How can I open a file via click it in windows with a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, file-association

I made a WPF program, just like the notepad in windows.

Now I modified the file associations of extension .txt to my program.

After I clicked a txt file, the problem comes: how can my WPF program get the path of the file? (I need to get the path to open the file.)

I consider it is an easy job. However, it seems there is not any tutorial about this in Google(maybe I miss its keyword).

Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: "wpf getting executable/command line arguments"

Comment: @bassfader I have never found it before. However, WPF not start with public static void Main(string[] args) while Winform does.

Comment: @MelonNG Yep, I didn't recall WPF being that kind of sassy :D So that wasn't a dupe - retracted. 
Another Article on the topic: https://sa.ndeep.me/post/how-to-create-smart-wpf-command-line-arguments/

Comment: If you don't get an answer by the time you figured it out, it may be helpful for others to answer your own question. (Assuming, there are in fact no dupes on SO to be found.)

Comment: @Fildor I prefer your way better for it is easier! Let me answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @Fildor 's tutorial in https://sa.ndeep.me/post/how-to-create-smart-wpf-command-line-arguments/

Others tutorial works also while this one is easier:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            foreach (string i in args)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(i);
            }
        }
```

The first index string in `args` is the path of your program.

The second index string in `args` is the path of the file.

Thanks for everyone helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the associated file that you open will be passed as an argument of the `Main` function.

For WPF it's slightly different since you don't have a `Main` method directly, usually. The entry point of your program should be your `<Application>` class.

In this case, arguments to the program are passed along to the `Startup` event in `Application` class:

XAML:

```
<Application ....
             Startup="app_Startup">  

    <!-- .... --->
</Application>
```

Codebehind:

```
    public partial class App: Application {  
        public static string[] Args;  
        void app_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {  
            // If no command line arguments were provided, don't process them if (e.Args.Length == 0) return;  
            if (e.Args.Length > 0) {  
                Args = e.Args;  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

(Example adapted from: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/wpf-command-line/)